# Selective merging rows by conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, conditional-statements

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

| ID | Time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | T1 | up |
| A | T2 | down |
| A | T3 | no |
| B | T1 | up |
| B | T2 | down |
| B | T3 | no |
| B | T1 | no |
| B | T2 | no |
| B | T3 | up |
| C | T1 | up |
| C | T2 | no |
| C | T3 | no |
| C | T1 | no |
| C | T2 | no |
| C | T3 | down |

I would like to merge it like this

| ID | Time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | T1 | up |
| A | T2 | down |
| A | T3 | no |
| B | T1 | up |
| B | T2 | down |
| B | T3 | up |
| C | T1 | up |
| C | T2 | no |
| C | T3 | down |

To explain: If A (ID) and B (Time) column are the same, then merge C (value) column; However, C (value) column is category type (only three kinds: up, down and no). When merging, always keep up or down, but not no if the merged rows contain both (up and no, or down and no).  If merged rows only contain no, then keep no.

I have more than 5000 rows in the file, so only want to keep the unique ID at specific Time with specific value (either up or down, or no if neither both).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID, Time) %>% filter(all(value == 'no') | value !='no') %>% distinct()
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   ID, Time [9]
  ID    Time  value
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     T1    up   
2 A     T2    down 
3 A     T3    no   
4 B     T1    up   
5 B     T2    down 
6 B     T3    up   
7 C     T1    up   
8 C     T2    no   
9 C     T3    down
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! However, another issue showed up after I used your suggestion. "Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "function"".

Answer (score 0):

This could also handle cases where both up and down appear, by prioritizing one of them in the ifelse clause:

```
df %>% group_by(A, B) %>% summarise(C = ifelse("up" %in% C, "up", ifelse("down" %in% C, "down", "no")))
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! One more scenario to consider. Thanks! However, I encountered the same issue as @Karthik S's suggestion. Any suggestions on this issue?

Comment: Hm... thats strange. If you add a small example data in code form i can try help you. Best would be using `dput` on a small sample that reproduces your error. Or create a data.frame manually.